# Data validation based on a first Data validation using Two onEdit functions in the same script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need help, I'm using an onEdit function to implement data validation based on a sheet. It is working fine when I use it alone. I can choose a type in Colonne 4 and a list appears in Colonne 5.
Then I'm trying to repeat this for colonne 7 based on the choice made in colonne 5.
I know an onedit function can only be used ones in a script, so I tried to do the second one in a new project but it didn't work. So I tried to do onEdit1 and onEdit2 and call them in a single onEdit(e) function but I had no success either. I would appreciate any help on that. Thanks in advance!

```
///////////////////Two data validation based on two different sheet, the second depends from the first one///////////////
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var parameters_sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Bases de données');
  var parameters_sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Validation - Quantité');
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('1. Dispatching');
var campAndGroup1 = parameters_sheet1.getRange(2, 1,parameters_sheet1.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
var campAndGroup2 = parameters_sheet2.getRange(2, 1,parameters_sheet2.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function dataval() {
  var list = ["a", "b", "g"];
  applyValidationToCell(list,cell);
}

function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1()
  onEdit2()
}

function onEdit1(e){
  var activeCell= e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r= activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName= activeCell.getSheet().getName();


  if(wsName=="1. Dispatching" && c === 4 && r>5){

    if(val=== ""){
      data_sheet.getRange(r,5).clearContent();
      data_sheet.getRange(r,5).clearDataValidations();
    } else {

   var filteredGroups = campAndGroup.filter(function(g){return g[0]=== val});
   var listToApply = filteredGroups.map(function(g){return g[1]});
    var cell = data_sheet.getRange(r,5);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }
  }
  
}


function onEdit2(e){
  var activeCell= e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r= activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName= activeCell.getSheet().getName();


  if(wsName=="1. Dispatching" && c === 5 && r>5){

    if(val=== ""){
      data_sheet.getRange(r,7).clearContent();
      data_sheet.getRange(r,7).clearDataValidations();
    } else {

   var filteredGroups = campAndGroup.filter(function(g){return g[0]=== val});
   var listToApply = filteredGroups.map(function(g){return g[1]});
    var cell = data_sheet.getRange(r,7);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  }
  }
  
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}

///////////////////fin validation///////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to pass the edit event object.

Simple fix: Replace

```
function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1()
  onEdit2()
}
```

by

```
function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1(e)
  onEdit2(e)
}
```

NOTE: The code can be optimized (reduce the code lines and the execution time) but that looks to be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Hi Rubén,  Thank you very much for your answer, it still doesn't work. I can imagine using a formula for the colonne 7 like this =sort(FILTER(E6:E,A2:A='Validation - Quantité'!E26),1,TRUE), it works, I'll just have to do it for the 75 rows of my file...

Comment: I suggest you to add more details about your spreadsheet structure to the question body including some sample data

Comment: Hi Ruben, Yes I was about to post an example. Here is a file with the table. When I use a single onedit to have a data validation for column E Client based on the choice of column  D Type and the sheet "Bases de données", it works perfectly, but then when I want to continue and have a data validation in column G Quantity based on the column F Concate1 and the sheet "Validation - Quantité" it stops working for both.  Thanks for your time ! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dxXZUVfKDuyORX7Rz9YaG2Lb07bn1WOKb8ILyL8UrYA/edit?usp=sharing